# Why is a delta resonance decay not a radioactive decay

Tags: radioactivity, baryons, proton-decay

A delta resonance decays as given in http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/delta.html . I wonder, why is it not a radioactive decay? In principle, most/all decays should be radioactive as it is a quite broad description:

> Radioactive decay (also known as nuclear decay, radioactivity or
>   nuclear radiation) is the process by which an unstable atomic nucleus
>   loses energy (in terms of mass in its rest frame) by emitting
>   radiation, such as an alpha particle, beta particle with neutrino or
>   only a neutrino in the case of electron capture, or a gamma ray or
>   electron in the case of internal conversion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay

Comment: my answer here should explain the difference  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414081/what-is-the-relationship-between-excitation-and-resonance/414403#414403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is that the technical definition is limited to atomic nuclei, the delta particle is definitely not a nucleus because it's lifetime is too short for playing any kind of role in an atom.

Said otherwise, it's impossible to form an atom out of a delta particle,  and as such you don't consider the decay of a delta particle to be the decay of an atomic nucleus. It's really a matter of definition/convention.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we use the word "decay" for a state that's either metastable or that decays through the electroweak interaction. States that fall into these categories will tend to be relatively long-lived.

An example similar to yours that is not usually described using the word "decay" is neutron emission. Because there is no Coulomb barrier, a state that is unbound with respect to neutron emission is not metastable. (Cf. alpha decay, which is the decay of a metastable state, hindered by having to get out through the Coulomb barrier.)

Comment: It would not be unusual for a particle physicist to say that a Delta "decays" to to a nucleon and a pion, but that is about context. We wouldn't generally use the adjective "radioactive" in this case.

Comment: I think decay is used even for unstable states, but as dmckee says radioactive is specifically meant to be used for (meta-stable) nuclei of protons and neutrons only.